# Java EXE on server accessed by client machines

Tags: java

My problem is this: I have a java executable application running in several machines (dispersed in a big warehouse) that connect to a SQL Server database on a Windows OS server,but now,the "top dogs" want the executable on the server and the clients all access the same executable,the one on the server...is that possible?That would ease the work when it comes to updating the executable,bottom line,only have to update on one machine.

Other thing,the application allows report printing (JasperReports),how does that work on client machine?Can it access their local printer or only the ones connected to the server?
Hope you can help me because I'm in a bit of a jam.

Thanks

Comment: Delivering java application through a server: did you check Java WebStart?

Comment: You could use a socket connection if the client interface doesn't change oftne, otherwise you're stuck with the same problem. If the application is not used often, then you could have people remote desktop into the central machine running your Java application.

Comment: @zenbeni,didn't know that one,had a look,seems a good solution!I created the executable package with Eclipse,hope it doesn't care about that...thanks!!
Just need to know if the printing "thing" can be a problem...